# how to get textbox area when i click first four radio buttons out five?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a Question with 5 radio buttons when I click on the first Four radio buttons textbox has to appear and for 5th radio button textbox must be hide

```
<input type="radio" name="satisify" ng-model="color" value="1" id="1star_Rate">
<input type-"text" id="txthdbh" ng-show="color=='1'">
```

Comment: Do you have any Code?? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: <input type="radio" name="satisify" ng-model="color" value="1" id="1star_Rate"><input type-"text" id="txthdbh" ng-show="color=='1'">

Comment: please edit your question, and put the code there in code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model on radio buttons two have two way bindings. Now use ng-show on text box which will depend on model value of the radio button

```js
 <script language="javascript">
        var questions = angular.module("questions", []);
        questions.controller("questionsCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.answer = "chennai";
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<body ng-app="questions" ng-controller="questionsCtrl">
    <div>which city you are from?</div>
    <div ng-bind="answer"></div>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="answer" value="chennai"/> chennai <br/>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="answer" value="mumbai" />mumbai <br />
    <input type="radio" ng-model="answer" value="calcutta" />calcutta <br />
    <input type="radio" ng-model="answer" value="delhi" />delhi <br />
    <input type="radio" ng-model="answer" value="other" />other <br />
    <input type="text" ng-show="answer!='other'" />
</body>
```

Comment: I already used that what exactly u told and my Question is "how can i bind the four values to the ng-show at their i'm getting problem"